# How to preselect a radio button inside of a Struts iterator based on the iterator value?

Tags: html, jsp, struts2, radio-button, struts-tags

I have the following lines of code inside of a Struts2 `<s:iterator>` tag.

```xml
<s:radio name="indicatorFlag"  list = "seqNoMap" value="indicatorFlag" /></div> 
<div><s:property  value = "indicatorFlag"/></div>
```

The `seqNoMap` is a defined on my action page as follows.

```java
seqNoMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
seqNoMap.put("Y", " Yes ");
seqNoMap.put("N", " No ");
```

The radio buttons show up on my page and passes the selection info back to the `indicatorFlag` field on the action page, but the `value="indicatorFlag"` in the `<s:radio>` tag does not preselect the radio button even though it does print out a Y or an N in the `<s:property>` tag on the second line.  The `indicatorFlag` changes values as the iterator goes through the list (it is a field of the objects in the list being iterated).  I have found several places which answer this question and I think I am applying the answers they give, but obviously I am missing something.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the relevant code for the `RefQuestionAction` action page.

```java
private HashMap<String, String> seqNoMap;  
private List<RefQuestionInfo> questionInfoList;
private String indicatorFlag;       // Char (1) flag

public RefQuestionAction(){
    seqNoMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    seqNoMap.put("Y", " Yes ");
    seqNoMap.put("N", " No ");
}
```

Here is the code which defines the object `RefQuestionInfo` (The `indicatorFlag` is the only field involved in this question).

```java
public class RefQuestionInfo extends BaseInfo implements Serializable {
    private int questionId;             
    private int seqNo;                  
    private String indicatorFlag;       
    private Date activeDate;            
    private Date inactiveDate;          
    private String question;
```

Here is the Struts2 code inside of the `<s:iterator>` tag.  I have stripped out most of the page code to focus on what my problem is.

```xml
<s:iterator value = "questionInfoList" var = "questionInfo">
    <s:radio name="indicatorFlag"  list = "seqNoMap" value="indicatorFlag" /> 
    <div><s:property  value = "indicatorFlag"/></div>
 </s:iterator>
```

The output looks like this.

[image: JSP page output]

I want the Yes or No radio value to be preselected based on the Y or N which is on the line after the radio buttons.

Comment: Can you show us more of your code ? The iterator, the indicatorFlag variable in the action, etc...

Comment: Stunning Curriculum, by the way :O

Comment: *The indicatorFlag changes values as the iterator goes through the list* - Not sure what do you mean by that. Could you post code for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your all radio buttons have the same name, that means that you can have only one of them selected. Assign different names for them using iterator `status`.

```xml
<s:iterator value="questionInfoList" var="questionInfo" status="stat">
  <s:radio name="indicatorFlag%{#stat.index}" list="seqNoMap" value="indicatorFlag" /> 
  <div><s:property value="indicatorFlag" /></div>
</s:iterator>
```

Note that you have variable with the same name `indicatorFlag` inside action and inside your `RefQuestionInfo` in the above code the one inside `RefQuestionInfo` will be used.